# trying to tab multiple words with a loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to create a loop that will tab my words from my text file like this:

```
            ServerLoop
    PostmasterMain
main
```

I've separated the words that I want in a text file, but I can't find a way to tab them all with \t with a loop

this is my current code

```
file1 = open("backtrace.txt", "r")


while True:
    line = file1.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    counter = 0
    for word in line.split():
      counter = counter + 1
      if counter == 4:
          print(word)
          break
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

```
with open('backtrace.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

for tab in reversed(range(len(lines))):
    print('\t' * tab, lines[-tab-1]) # Subtraction is needed because the for loop is reversed
```

The result would be:

```
                 ServerLoop

         PostmasterMain

 main
```

Comment: i just have one more question where would i put the script and how would i split it if i don't put it in the script? thanks you

Comment: please answer as soon as you can

Comment: Hey dude, try to be grateful giving some love to the answer e.g. up vote before continue asking over and over.

Comment: i did but my reputation is only 1 so it doesn't show. i'm grateful you saw this post and have the answer so i up voted it

Comment: i just want to know where i put it or how do i split it. i'm just asking for clarification. please answer as soon as you can

Comment: I don't know what you mean by where to place or split the code. How is your current script distributed ?

Comment: the script you gave me i want it to be in the same program. i've tried a lot of different things but none of them work. so i splited the words but i can't the script you gave me to tab the words

Comment: I don't still know what you want, the script is working and I created `backtrace.txt` file 
putting a word (ServerLoop, PostmasterMain and main)on each line

Comment: the file contents i something like this : linelinelinelineserverlooplinelineline i can split it but how do i get the script to print the split words. i can't get your script to work with mine. so where should i put the script or what do i need to add . the split words come out in the output. the result i usually get is this: linelinelinelineserverlooplinelineline. everything is tabbed but not split